# SWIFT: Is it possible to access stored properties of a class inside its extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, tvos

```
class BibliothequesViewController: UIViewController {
 static let sharedInstance = BibliothequesViewController()
   var presentedBy: UIViewController?
 }
```

I tried to access, both `sharedInstance` and `presentedBy` inside the extension:

```
extension BibliothequesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
       override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            //Trying to present by using presentBy property
        let vc = segue.destination as! presentedBy
        // This throws this error: Use of undeclared type 'presentedBy' 
        let vc = segue.destination as! BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy
        // This throws this error: Static property 'sharedInstance' is not a member type of 'BibliothequesViewController'
       }
  }
```

The first error makes sense.
The second one doesn't as I have used `BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy` in other areas in the app and it works fine.

The point is I want to know is there a way to access `sharedInstance` or `presentedBy` inside the extension?

Comment: You need to specify a type after `as!` not a variable: `let vc = segue.destination as! BibliothequesViewController`

Comment: But to answer your question, yes, you can access a stored property from an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of `as` is a type, not a variable. The only thing you know about `presentedBy` is that it's of type `Optional<UIViewController>`. And `segue.destination` is of type UIViewController. Since every type can be promoted to the optional of its type, your `as` isn't doing anything. When you're done, you know it's a UIViewController. You're good to go. You can call any UIViewController methods you want, but you could do that anyway.

In short: your `as!` isn't doing anything. Just get rid of it.

(As @Runt8 notes, yes, you can definitely access stored properties from an extension, but that has nothing to do with your actual question.)